# Moving a GID shape righ and left

Tags: c#, gdi+

I use this code to move the shape up and down (`viewport` is the place I draw the shape)

```
float zoom = -viewport.Height * 0.20f;

viewport.Offset(2f, zoom);

Invalidate();
```

I want also to move it right and left, but I can't figure it out

Comment: What is the type of `viewport`? Is it a `Rectangle` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7831e7fe.aspx) method moved the rectangle both horizontally and vertically, by the amounts you specify in the parameters.

You passed `2f` as the first parameter of the `Offset` method, which is responsible for horizontal (left and right) movement of the rectangle. Just pass the amount you need, and you are done.

Comment: Now you are moving it by 2 pixels, which is not visible on a 96dpi screen (normal monitors). Try some larger amount (100, 200, ...) and you see that it moves.

Comment: Yes. I hadn't actually realised that offset(x,y) actually refers to x,y axis. Thought the y part was the distance or something. Thanks